# Link to a function

Tags: javascript

I am building a simple framework to work with DOM elements. I have about 40 big functions in the framework.

Framework function is :

```
var $ = function(a) { /* content */ };
```

And it's functions :

```
Dev.FN = {
 /* big functions here */
};
```

Here is how I include functions in the framework :

```
     if($.FN) {
       $.FN.em = em;
       return $.FN;
     }
     $.FN = { em : em };
     for(var b in Dev.FN) {
       if(Dev.FN.hasOwnProperty(b)) {
         $.FN[b] = Dev.FN[b];
       }
     }
     return $.FN;
```

The problem : **It creates my 40 big functions for each framework call**, i mean :
if I call `$(element1)` it creates 40 functions for it, then `$(element2)` again 40 big functions and so on..

**How to link to functions from `Dev.FN` without creating them on each `$(element)` call?**

*PS: I have also tried the following, but I don't know if it helps :*

```
     for(var b in Dev.FN) {
       if(Dev.FN.hasOwnProperty(b)) {
         $.FN[b] = function() {
           return Dev.FN[b].apply(this, arguments);
         };
       }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Stick your declarations in an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/):

```
Dev.FN = (function () {
 /* big functions here */
}) ();
```

> In JavaScript, every function, when invoked, creates a new execution context. ... In many cases, you won’t need multiple “instances” of whatever your makeWhatever function returns, and can make do with just a single instance

Comment: It seems that it will create global functions from Dev.FN. 1) What if Dev.FN contains reserved function like "setInterval" or another existing function? 2) with return I can do the following : $(element).option(), but if to do (function(){})() what will it return? .option() will become unavailable..